# Compare one column in one file, against another column and if they match, append column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I would like to compare one column from one file against another column in another file. If the columns match, I would like to append the first column from the first file, as the first column of the second file.

File1

```
FID IID
456 2
123 1
789 3
112 4
```

File2

```
IID column1 column2 column3... column464
1 Value11 Value12 etc etc ... etc
7 Value71 Value72 etc etc ... etc
2 Value21 Value22 etc etc ... etc
6 Value61 Value62 etc etc ... etc
3 Value31 Value32 etc etc ... etc
```

Desired output

```
FID IID column1 column2 column3... column464
123 1 Value11 Value12 etc etc ... etc
456 2 Value21 Value22 etc etc ... etc
789 3 Value31 Value32 etc etc ... etc
```

Comment: Edited and updated now. I know it would be appropriate to use awk, but I really do not know where to start.

Comment: You can use join command, but before you need to sort files (with sort command)

Comment: Is it important that the resulting file start with FID column? Because you're comparing it by IID column...

Comment: I have considering switching the FID and IID column, but then there are another 462 columns, and writing them out all in the order of how I want them to be may be tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { id[$2]=$1; next } ($1 in id){ print id[$1], $0}' file1 file2
```

within first action block we are reading the file1 into an associated array called *`id`* where they keys are the column $2 and their value is column $1; about the `NR==FNR` which is an always true condition when processing the first input file which are awk's internal environment variables and NR (**N**umber of **R**ecords) update for every input as same to FNR (**F**ile **N**umber of **R**ecord) but FNR reset for the each next input file.

then within next action block we are checking if that first column $1 of the file2 exist in the *`id`* array then print its corresponding value `id[$1]` followed by the entire line $0 of the file2.

Answer (score 0):

For a limited number of fields, try

```
join -12 -21 -o1.1,0,2.2,2.3,2.4  <(sort -nk2,2 file1) <(sort -n file2) 2>/dev/null
FID IID column1 column2 column3...
123 1 Value11 Value12 etc
456 2 Value21 Value22 etc
789 3 Value31 Value32 etc
```

but with your alluded number of fields, the format might become somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: there are a lot of columns based on the header column464, so I don't think so it's can easily done by join as comparing columns are also vary between two files or swamping the columns with another command after that

Comment: interestingly it's can be done with the help of the brace expansion `join -12 -21 -o1.1 -o2.{1..464} <(sort -nk2,2 file1) <(sort -n file2)`

Comment: except for -o2 expansion needs to start from 1 also as in `join -1 2 -2 1 -o1.1 -o2.{1..264} <(sort -nk2 file1) <(sort -n file2)`